# Best practices for indexing with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

I want to select rows based on a mask, `idx`. I can think of two different possibilities, either using `iloc` or just using brackets. I have shown the two possibilities (on a dataframe `df`) below. Are they both equally viable?

```
idx = (df["timestamp"] >= 5) & (df["timestamp"] <= 10)
idx = idx.values
hr = df["hr"].iloc[idx]
timestamps = df["timestamp"].iloc[idx]
```

or the following one:

```
idx = (df["timestamp"] >= 5) & (df["timestamp"] <= 10)
hr = df["hr"][idx]
timestamps = df["timestamp"][idx]
```

Comment: Your question boils down to whether you use `df['col'].iloc[idx]` or just `[idx]`, where `idx` is a vector of **boolean** (not int). So you're only asking about the boolean mask case.

Comment: Where does one begin when talking about pandas indexing. Maybe the docs are a good start. Don't ever mix and chain indexing operations like this. You're going to be in for a world of hurt.

Comment: I've edited your question's title into something I am confident a lot of people are going to be searching for. Let's see.

Comment: By the way, would you mind making it a habit to upvote/accept answers you find helpful? It helps the community, and I notice you don't seem to do it very often.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they are not the same. One uses direct syntax while the other relies on chained indexing.

The crucial points are:

- [`pd.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is used primarily for integer position-based indexing.
- [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is most often used with labels or Boolean arrays.
- Chained indexing, i.e. via `df[x][y]`, is [explicitly discouraged](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) and is never necessary.
- `idx.values` returns the `numpy` array representation of `idx` series. This cannot feed `.iloc` and is not necessary to feed `.loc`, which can take `idx` directly.

Below are two examples which would work. In either example, you can use similar syntax to mask a dataframe or series. For example, `df['hr'].loc[mask]` would work as well as `df.loc[mask]`.

#### iloc

Here we use `numpy.where` to extract integer indices of `True` elements in a Boolean series. `iloc` does accept Boolean arrays but, in my opinion, this is less clear; "i" stands for integer.

```
idx = (df['timestamp'] >= 5) & (df['timestamp'] <= 10)
mask = np.where(idx)[0]
df = df.iloc[mask]
```

#### loc

Using `loc` is more natural when we are already querying by specific series.

```
mask = (df['timestamp'] >= 5) & (df['timestamp'] <= 10)
df = df.loc[mask]
```

- When masking only rows, you can omit the `loc` accessor altogether and use `df[mask]`.
- If masking by rows and filtering for a column, you can use `df.loc[mask, 'col_name']`

[Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) is fundamental to `pandas`: there is no substitute for reading the official documentation.

Comment: Is using mask = idx.values instead of mask = np.where(idx)[0] not also working?

Comment: No, it won't work. Because `idx.values` will just give a Boolean array, which cannot feed `.iloc`.

Comment: According to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html ".iloc is primarily integer position based (from 0 to length-1 of the axis), but may also be used with a boolean array"

Comment: iloc can only take a numpy array but not the series, otherwise I'm getting an error. So idx.values seems to be neccessary

Comment: @machinery, True, not looking to replicate the docs here though (much more available there). But I've updated again :).

Answer (score 3):

Don't mix `__getitem__` based indexing and (i)loc based. Use one or the other. I prefer (i)loc when you're accessing by index, and `__getitem__` when you're accessing by column or using boolean indexing.

Here's some commonly bad methods of indexing:

```
df.loc[idx].loc[:, col]   
df.loc[idx][col]                
df[column][idx]          
df[column].loc[idx]
```

The correct method for all the above would be `df.loc[idx, col]`. If `idx` is an integer label, use `df.loc[df.index[idx], col]`.

Most of these solutions will cause issues down the pipeline (mainly in the form of a SettingWithCopyWarning), when you try assigning to them, because these create views and are tied to the original DataFrame they're viewing into.

The correct solution to all these versions is `df.iloc[idx, df.columns.get_loc(column)]` Note that `idx` is an array of integer indexes, and `column` is a string label. Similarly for `loc`.

If you have an array of booleans, use `loc` instead, like this: `df.loc[boolean_idx, column]`

Furthermore, these are fine: `df[column]`, and `df[boolean_mask]`

There are rules for indexing a single row or single column. Depending on how it is done, you will get either a Series or DataFrame. So, if you want to index the 100th row from a DataFrame `df` as a DataFrame slice, you need to do:

```
df.iloc[[100], :]  # `:` selects every column
```

And not

```
df.iloc[100, :]
```

And similarly for the column-based indexing.

Lastly, if you want to index a single scalar, use `at` or `iat`.

---

OTOH, for your requirement, I would suggest a third alternative:

```
ts = df.loc[df.timestamp.between(5, 10), 'timestamp']
```

Or if you're subsetting the entire thing,

```
df = df[df.timestamp.between(5, 10)]
```

Comment: @BenMares Seems like the wording was bad there. I meant to add the correction in comments next to the incorrect method, but later realised all of them are different ways of incorrectly writing the same expression. See my [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50662237/revisions) here.